# How do I install `gresource` on Fedora?

Tags: utilities, gdm

I'd like to change the background image of my login screen (Fedora 23, GNOME desktop).  The [Arch wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GDM#Log-in_screen_background_image) has a write-up on how to do it.  Basically it involves extracting the .gresource binary that lives in `/usr/share/gnome-shell/theme`, editing some lines, then recompiling it, since `gdm` uses a binary for theming.

The wiki post shows a shell script that does the extraction of the `.gresource` binary, but it calls a tool called `gresource`:

```
for r in `gresource list $gst`; do
         gresource extract $gst $r >$workdir${r/#\/org\/gnome\/shell/} 
done
```

However, when I try to use `gresource` I get an error saying that `bash: gresource: command not found`.  So it doesn't appear to be installed.  Nor is it available via `dnf`.  I found an [Ubuntu post mentioning](https://askubuntu.com/a/654819) that it is part of a library package called `libglib2.0-bin`, and that it is usually installed alongside `GLib`.

How would I install `gresource` on Fedora?

Using Fedora 23, GNOME desktop, 4.2.6 kernel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just install GLib.

`$ wget http://ftp.gnome.org/pub/gnome/sources/glib/2.46/glib-2.46.2.tar.xz`

`$ tar xpvf glib-2.46.2.tar.xz`

`$ cd glib-2.46.2`

`$ ./configure --prefix=/usr --with-pcre=system && make`

`$ make install`

The dependencies, install & user guide can be found here:

http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/svn/general/glib2.html

Answer (score 3):

On Fedora, it is also possible to get the gresource binary without installing `GLib` from sources by just installing the `glib2-devel` package:-

```
su -c 'dnf install glib2-devel'
```

(or `sudo dnf install glib2-devel` if you have `sudo` rights)

This will make gresource available as `/usr/bin/gresource`.